# CSS transitions parent to match a childs final height

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

Jade example

```
div.parent
    div.child1
    div.child2
```

Child1 is visible on load, based on a click, Child1 will become hidden and Child2 will become visible.  Another click can reverse this.

When hiding / un-hiding the children should transition via height change - from 100% to 0% and visa versa.
The parent should transition also via a height change to match the newly visible child.

Visually child1 will appear to "roll up" while child2 is "rolling down", parent will extend or contract depending on final size.

Can this be done with CSS transitions?

Comment: Transition part can be done with CSS but the hide/unhide part which triggers the change can't be done.

Comment: @Harry agree with you, to hear from the "end animation" event, you will need JavaScript.

Comment: Unless the divs have a set height you can't transition/animate to/from `auto/100%` either.

Comment: @Paulie_D: That can be overcome to a good extent by setting `max-height` (to a height higher than the max expected) and transitioning that.

Comment: Well it *can* be done, @Harry, with some combination of checkboxes. However it doesn't mean it *should be done*, but I'll try it as an extra to my answer it just for the kicks

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia: Depends on the ordering of the elements (and quite a lot of other unknowns really). You can't modify an element higher/before in the DOM tree so the checkboxes need to be at the appropriate level.

Comment: @Harry Yes, using max-height is one alternative but I think that depends on *knowing* that max-height in advance (or setting some probably unreasonable number) and (hopefully) this not interfering with the parent height. Frankly, this is a simple few lines of JS/JQ so I'd go that way.

Comment: @Paulie_D: +1 on that last line. I fully agree that JS (or a jQuery slideToggle) would be much simpler here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done ONLY if you know previously the final height of the children.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

button.onclick = function(){
  parent.classList.toggle('toggle');
}
```

```css
.child1,
.child2 {
  height: 100px;
  background: #faa;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.child2 {
  background: #aff;
  height: 0;
}

.toggle .child1 {
  height: 0;
}

.toggle .child2 {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Something here</div>
  <div class="child2">Or here</div>
</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

You can also do it even if you don't know the final height, but it's really too hacky to be worth implementing in pure CSS. It has something to do with adding a transition and a max-height of X where X >>> height. But it has an issue when folding into a small thing, as there's a delay caused by 100 * (X - height) % of the time.

Based on the comments (and for the kicks), you can also do it without Javascript, but I don't really recommend it because it's not so clear (JS is normally the controller):

```css
.child1,
.child2 {
  height: 100px;
  background: #faa;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child2 {
  background: #aff;
  height: 0;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;
}

:checked ~ .child1 {
  height: 0;
}

:checked ~ .child2 {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" name="el" />
  <div class="child1">Click me</div>
  <div class="child2">Now me</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Upvoted for your effort even though I wouldn't really recommend CSS for this :)